# NAT port forwarding not working, while ssh tunnel does

Tags: apache, iptables, portforwarding, lxc

I have a LXC container apache2 installation (container listening on 192.168.122.179:80).

The host is 10.138.141.216.

If I tunnel via ssh:
 ssh -L 45678:192.168.122.179:80 myuser@10.138.141.216
from my pc I get the apache2 page (browser to http://localhost:45678)

BUT if I disconnect the ssh tunnel and only use iptables http://10.138.141.216:45678 won't work:

```
[~]$ sudo iptables -t nat -L -n -v
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    9   564 DNAT       tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp dpt:45678 to:192.168.122.179:80

Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 RETURN     all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     224.0.0.0/24
    2   656 RETURN     all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     255.255.255.255
  606 36360 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
    0     0 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24     masq ports: 1024-65535
  725  101K MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24
```

I can see the pkts & bytes numbers change whenever I refresh the page in the browser, but all I get is "This site can’t be reached".

So ssh tunnel works, while the iptables rule does not...

UPDATE:

using tcpdump I can see "tcp port eba unreachable", why???

```
14:46:40.672318 IP 10.79.41.37.57504 > mymachine.eba: Flags [S], seq 2646922897, win 8192, options [mss 1360,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK,unknown-33 0x21cc167ee1203a070000], length 0
14:46:40.672402 IP mymachine > 10.79.41.37: ICMP mymachine tcp port eba unreachable, length 72
```

wget http://192.168.122.179 works from inside the host...

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why but LXC by default adds this rules:

```
REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
```

These were not visible when using

iptables **-t any** -L -n -v

Removing "-t any" showed them.
Removing those rules did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Apache is usually configured by hosts. Each hosts listens to requests from specific domain names.

In order for your host to be reachable, you need to listen for the IP itself or se the hostname or set the default host in your Apache hosts-configuration.

You can test whether your host configuration works using wget or curl to perform a get request on localhost.

If Apache works, make sure there aren't any conflicting iptables rules.

Comment: but I have <VirtualHost *:80> and "Listen 80" on apache config files, wouldn't that listen to all interfaces?

Comment: You could test it using curl, sending a GET request to localhost from within your ssh connection.

Comment: I think that would not work as iptables are not supposed to work on the loopback interface?

Comment: That would be the point; testing the response you get from your apache. If your apache works for sure. The next thing would be to indeed get it through your iptables.